# Practical Example of requestDefaultSuggestions for GWT SuggestBox onFocus

Tags: java, gwt, suggestbox

We have been asked to update our SuggestBox to show a default set of suggestions when the user tabs onto the field.  We registered a FocusHandler on the SuggestBox with the intention of using the requestDefaultSuggestions(Request r, Callback c) method on our implementation of SuggestOracle.

The documentation informs us that the Request query should be null in order for this to work.  Easy enough.  However, the larger question is about the Callback object.

I assumed that I would simply create an anonymous class that implements the onSuggestionsReady method and pass that into the method call above.

Example:

```
    Callback callback = new Callback() {
        public void onSuggestionsReady(Request request, Response response) {
            // do something!
        }
    };
```

What I'm stuggling to figure out is what does the Callback do with the results in order to populate them into the SuggestBox upon return of the call (i.e. - the 'do something')?  Based on my review of SuggestBox and SuggestionDisplay I can't figure out a way to pass in the response suggestions to the box.  My searches have shown others with similar questions but I have yet to see anyone post the answer.   It seems like something one should be able to do fairly easily, so I'm not sure if I'm just confused about how to invoke the requestDefaultSuggestions method call or if I'm coming at the problem from the wrong angle.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction and help me get this documented for the next developer to struggle on it.

Comment: Are you using the standard GWT [SuggestBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html)? It knows to call `SuggestOracle#requestDefaultSuggestions()` if user entered no text.

Comment: Boris - Yes, the requestDefaultSuggestions method is called the very first time the GWT widget is touched.  However, the default values for this field (in our case) can change based on values entered in other fields on the form.  If the user comes back to this field there is no additional call to the requestDefaultSuggestions method.

Comment: Ended up storing off the Callback object made by the first call to requestDefaultSuggestions and then using that callback in all subsequent requests that were wired into the FocusHandler event processing.  Works like a champ, although I would still like to know how to instantiate a Callback object if someone knows.

Comment: Developer Note: We noticed that the getDefaultSuggestions was being called automatically when the user would tab into the SuggestBox(onFocus), but not when the user would mouse click on the SuggestBox(onClick). To resolve this required us to add a ClickHandler to the SuggestBox.getValueBox.  However, that left us with the initial issue. If this was the first time the SuggestBox had gained focus we had no callback object.  The simple answer was to call showSuggestionList() which will request default suggestions.  Might have been obvious to others, but took some digging for me to figure it out.